# How do I refresh Winforms DataGridView?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, refresh

I have two `DataGridView`s in a tab and the `DataSource` of the second grid is based on the row selection in first grid. The problem is I cannot get the grid to refresh after some values have been inserted or updated in the prior tabs. It works fine if I click on the row but it is not working if I select the row programmatically (i.e. first row). I have tried the following but it failed to refresh.

```
daProgram.ClearBeforeFill = true
daProgram.fill(dsProgram)
bsProgram.ResetBindings(true) -- binding source also tried false
dgvProgram.DataSource=bsProgram -- rebinding the control
```

I also tried:

```
dgvProgram.DataSource=nothing
```

and

```
dgvProgram.DataBindings.clear()
```

Nothing works :-(

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out in this.

Comment: have you tried dgvProgram.Refresh() ?

Comment: bsProgram.ResetCurrentItem(), it works on textbox, datetimepicker, etc, dunno if it can work on datagridview too

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding your data properly?

http://www.theserverside.net/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=31014

http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/256204-refresh-databindings-winform

Answer (score 0):

I have read a few things about this, and too found ResetBindings not to work.

If you're using Table Adapters, just call the fill method (the method that auto gets added in to your Form Load event).

I've read things that say you *shouldn't* call Fill. I see no reason why not. It simply re-queries the data, which is exactly what a refresh should do.

```
Me.YourTableAdapter.Fill(Me.YourDataSet.YourDataTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
dgvProgram.DataSource=null;
```